# Can we achieve the same computational scaling with tensorflow as we could with MPI?

Tags: tensorflow, mpi

the reason that I'm asking this question is because I've seen code around the web where people use the MPI for distributed computing in order to scale their computational models. What I can't wrap my head around is that most of those examples I'm referring to are written in tensorflow. Now given that tensorflow already implements mpi and gRPC the question that I'm asking is if we can achieve the same results purely with tensorflow instead of using MPI?

To put in other words what are some pros and cons in comparison to MPI vs TF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TF is a machine learning framework, and MPI is a Message Passing library. Parallel TF is built on top of MPI (TF is not an implementation of MPI)

Bottom line, you cannot compare apples and oranges, nor MPI and TF.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am not directly comparing MPI to TF, rather I'm implicitly comparing MPI to gRPC which is what TF offers, so sort of speaking even if they might be different technologies they're still apples to apples to me since their end goal is the same, i.e. distributed computing. BTW are there any benchmarks on these stuff?

Comment: gRPC is a Remote Procedure Call library (that uses HTTP/2, and hence works anywhere but with a lot of overhead) whereas MPI is a Message Passing library (works generally on a cluster but near wire speed). Apples and oranges are both delicious fruits, it is imho incorrect to compare them though.

Comment: *their end goal is the same, i.e. distributed computing* Well, MPI is really targeted at parallel computing, which partially overlaps with distributed computing, but I don't think it's useful to think of MPI as a general-purpose distributed computing framework.